# Does an ElasticSearch Alias change the underlying index files

Tags: elasticsearch

If I create an alias in ElasticSearch over two or more indices, does that change something in the storage of those indices? Ie. are they merged on the filesystem somewhere or is the merging done on the API level?

Answer (score 1):

There is no merge of any kind. An alias is just a logical representation ([from the doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#indices-aliases)):

> The index aliases API allow to alias an index with a name, with all APIs automatically converting the alias name to the actual index name. An alias can also be mapped to more than one index, and when specifying it, the alias will automatically expand to the aliases indices.

When you query the API with an alias, ES will resolve the alias and run your query on every index which is part of the alias.